# mongoDB maximum number of shards

Tags: mongodb

According to this:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cluster-additional-settings/

"You can set the number of shards to deploy with the sharded cluster. Your cluster can have between 1 and 50 shards, inclusive."

But according to MongoDB employee:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/maximum-number-of-shards/98230

"I’m not aware of a specific limit on number of shards. For a similar discussion on limits, please see my response on Database and collection limitations - #2 by Stennie 108."

and:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/limits-on-data-size-2/173571

"MongoDB offers horizontal scale-out using sharding: While a single ‘Replica Set’ (aka a shard in a sharded cluster) cannot exceed 4TB of physical storage, you can use as many shards as you want in your MongoDB Atlas sharded cluster."

Please resolve the contradiction or my mis understanding?

Comment: The former is a restriction applied to their hosted database (Atlas) offering as opposed to a seemingly higher maximum that the underlying database technology supports. Probably a question for the vendor about the restriction on Atlas itself

Comment: The last quote "you can use as many shards as you want in your MongoDB Atlas sharded cluster". So even if just Atlas, there is uncertainty.

Comment: Do you think, you will ever hit the limit of 50 shards (e.i. 200TB) in your application?

Comment: I need to divide my collection into shards not because of its size, but because I need to take advantage of divide and conquer in one of my queries. My collection is expected to have 10 million documents, which is maybe only 10 gigabytes. But still, the more shards, the faster the query will be.

Comment: But still, the more shards, the faster the query will be. - Yes, but only if the query contains the shard key.

Comment: Actually, the query will require a scatter and gather from the shards. Because it must return a list of users, which is hopeless randomly and evenly distributed across the shards.